# specman e free tool for learning purpose

Tags: specman, e

I am learning specman e for design verification, I have read some tutorials and learned some code, but i could not find a free tool to try some codes that I learn.

so, my question is there any free tool like DVT eclipse that I can use it to learn specman e?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it yet myself, but I read that https://www.edaplayground.com/ recently added support for Specman/e.

Comment: Thank you cmagu, i have used this site, but still not what i want, it works just with basic codes, its libraries are hidden.